# Using python to store and update MS access table

Tags: python, sql, ms-access, pyodbc

I am using a python script to update a field called LT_Completion_Metric that is in a MS access table, the table is called PROMIS_LT. For a given SubjectID, this completion metric calculates the number of records with the value "Completed" in the Status field divided by the total number of records that SubjectID has in the PROMIS_LT table. The SubjectID is unique and acts like a primary in the PROMIS_LT table. I should also note that each SubjectID has several records in the PROMIS_LT table. The LT_Completion_Mertic field values are calculated using the LTCompletionMetricQuery which is an SQL query(in the code below). Since the value of the LT_Cmopletion_Metric changes due to the Status field changing every week or so, I have used the python script to calculate, store and update the value of the LT_Completion_Metric field in the PROMIS_LT table.

However, my script is not storing any values at all into the PROMIS_LT table. Please look at the python script below and help me identify the source of error.

I will also note that in MS access I made the LT_Completion_Metric field a Number datatype and then set the field size as Double in order to keep the datatype in python script the same as in the ms access table.

Any input would be greatly appreciated

```
import pyodbc
import time


db = ' have omitted this for security purposes

def update_LT_Completion_Metric():
    LTCompletionMetricQuery = "SELECT SubjectID, AVG(IIF(Status = 'Completed',1.0,0))  AS completion_metric_query_result FROM PROMIS_LT GROUP BY SubjectID"
    cursor.execute(LTCompletionMetricQuery)

    #converts LTCompletionMetricQuery to dictionary 
    columns = [col[0] for col in cursor.description]
    rows = [dict(zip(columns, row)) for row in cursor.fetchall()]


    #iterate through all the rows in LTCompletionMetricQuery 
    #and use their values to update PROMIS_LT table


    for record in rows: 

        #assigns a name for the value of the SubjectID key
        subjectid = record["SubjectID"]
        #assigns a name for the value of the completion_metric_query_result 
        completion_metric = record["completion_metric_query_result"] 

        update_promis_lt_table('PROMIS_LT', 'LT_Completion_Metric', completion_metric , 'SubjectID', subjectid)



def update_promis_lt_table(table_name, column_to_update, column_value, where_column, where_value):
    update_query = "UPDATE %s SET %s = ? WHERE %s = ?" % (table_name, column_to_update, where_column)
    cursor.execute(update_query, (column_value, where_value))
    conn.commit()

#run the updatecompletion metric function run 10  seconds
while True:
    update_LT_Completion_Metric()
        time.sleep(10) #make function to sleep for 10 seconds
```

Comment: It's been a long time since I've used access, but I recall how quirky the queries seemed to be sometimes. See if changing the update sql to: `UPDATE %s SET [%s] = ? WHERE [%s] = ?` makes any difference? I realize the use of `[]` is typically needed for fields with spaces, but checking a few update query examples shows the `[]` use with or without spaces.

Comment: Did that help, or same result?

Comment: same result.. not sure what's going on